# AWS Polly - How to reduce character limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I am working on a project where we need to restrict the number of characters that users can translate using Polly - for example 20000 characters per user/login. Is there a way we can do this?

Comment: Where are you seeing this limit? [Quotas in Amazon Polly - Amazon Polly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/limits.html) is saying there is a limit of 100,000 billed characters (which excludes SSML tags) for `SpeechSynthesisTask` and 3000 characters for `SynthesizeSpeech`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

You would need to write your own code that passes the request to Polly, but first checks that the size is within limits.

The flow would be:

- User sends text to your app
- App checks length of text
- If okay, app sends the request to Amazon Polly
- App passes response back to user

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to restrict access using a role?

Comment: By default, users in AWS have no permission to do anything. Users can only call an API if they have been granted permission. So, rather than thinking about "restricting" access, simply **don't grant them access** to the API call in the Role.